# Delete pixel with value 0 255 in np array

Tags: python, opencv

I am using Opencv and python 3.6 
I have an image with this dimensions:

```
depth = depth[0:240, 96:320]
```

So an image of (240,224). The image is in grayscale, and I don't want consider the 2 extreme values 0 / 255 of the pixels intensity.

I already have a loop in my script. I think that I have to add a line where I take off these pixels like this:

```
for b in depth: #cicle already existing
    if b < 255 and b > 0:  #added line
        a = a+1
        if a <= 121 and a >= 118:
            for f in range(25, 223):
                #print((x+b)%33)
                soundArr[int((f-25)/6)] = soundArr[int((f-25)/6)]+b[f]
```

but I obtain the error:

```
The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

So how do I delete those pixels?

Comment: Each `b` in `for b in depth:` is an array corresponding to each of the rows ni `depth`. `b < 255` and `b > 0` both produce boolean arrays indicating whether or not each element meets the condition. When you do `b < 255 and b > 0` you are trying to produce one single boolean value from two boolean arrays, which doesn't really make sense. You can do `b < 255 & b > 0` to produce a third boolean array indicating which elements meet _both_ conditions, but it still doesn't make sense to use it as the condition of an `if` block. What do you want to do with the extreme values?

Comment: what i want to do is to delete the white and black pixel. 
So if a pixel is 0 or 255 don't consider it

Comment: But what do you mean by "delete" exactly? If your image has shape `(240, 224)` you can not just "remove" pixels, the shape must stay the same. If you don't want to consider them for some algorithm you can mask them or something like that.

Comment: ok sorry, I edited my question to be more clear. By delete I mean to not consider 0 and 255 as values in the algorithm following ( See code up )

Comment: Looks like you just need to change your loop to iterate over each _pixel_ as @jdehesa is indicating. As is, you are iterating over each _row_.

Comment: if i set " if b < 255 & b > 0: " i got this errror:
 ufunc 'bitwise_and' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly you can use [numpy.where](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) in order to find the indices of 0 and 255 in your depth image. Then when you iterate over the image you can disregard the results from numpy.where.